# Control when Firebase Database syncs data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm thinking moving an Android app's persistent data to Firebase Database. Currently I use Sqlite with a Python HTTP REST service.

In the app, I have a big list of cities, called `citiesList`. Since the list is quite big and hardly updated, I don't want the app fetch the list whenever it goes online.

My current strategy is provide a `citiesListVersion`. When the app goes online, it checks `citiesListVersion`. If the server's `citiesListVersion` is newer, the app will fetch `citiesList` from server. Otherwise, the app continues working with the cached data.

My question is: can I keep my current strategy when moving to Firebase Database? As I understand, Firebase tries to sync data whenever the app goes online.

Comment: It only tries to sync what you tell it to sync. If you tell it to only check citiesListVersion that's exactly what it'll do.

Comment: Nothing in your database is synchronized until a client adds a listener to some location.  As long as the listener is added, you will receive updates for only the data under that location.  When you remove the listener, the updates will stop.  When the app dies, the updates will stop.  So, just control your adds and removes to the times when you want new data.

Comment: You should really walk through the [Firebase Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) and write some code to see how Firebase works. As mentioned you can add observers that automatically synchronize data when data changes. You can also manually get data without adding observers. For example; when the user clicks the Load Cities button, it will load the cities at that time only.